# xenserver: installation via kickstart file after adding storage

Tags: xen, xenserver, kickstart

```
export MGUID=`xe vm-install template=centos6 new-name-label="centos 6 test install 3"`
xe vm-disk-add disk-size=11GiB vm=$MGUID sr-uuid=$STORAGE_UID device=0
xe vm-param-set uuid="$MGUID" PV-args="ks=http://server.com/ks.cfg ksdevice=eth0"
xe vm-param-set uuid="$MGUID" other-config:install-repository="http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/centos/6/os/x86_64/"
xe vm-start uuid=$MGUID
```

when i do this i get a error that there is no bootloader. if i add a disk to the template and omit the 2nd command everything works fine.

so the question: how can i boot into installation after adding disk(s)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to follow along here:

When I run the vm-disk-add line, i get

"A device with the name given already exists on the selected VM
device: 0
"

Meaning that I already have a disk at position 0.  This is true; my template includes a disk in slot 0 when it's made.

I guess my question is, why do you want to do it this way.  What if you put a disk on the template with a small size, and then expand it to the size you want before doing the vm-start.  Would this have the same desired effect?

Does this page help you at all?:

http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=290306&start=0&tstart=0

Comment: well it would somehow have the same effect. none the less i would like to figure out why this happens and how i can get into "installation from kickstart mode"